# how to find number of array list from contains string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, unity-game-engine

how to find number of array list same as contains string, i want make contains string "guess1" get "answer1" and "guess2" get "answer2". how to find n number of array same as contains string?

```
public class FindContainsText : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text text;
public InputField intext;

List<string> guess = new List<string>();
List<string> answer = new List<string>();

private int n;

void Start()
{
    guess.Add("test1");
    guess.Add("test2");

    answer.Add("answer1");
    answer.Add("answer2");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    foreach (string x in guess)
    {
        
        if (intext.text.ToLower().Contains(x.ToLower()))
        {
            text.text = answer[n];
            return;
        } 
    }
    text.text = "not found";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use `Dictionary` type.

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> guessAnswerDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void Start()
{
    guessAnswerDict["test1"] = "answer1";
    guessAnswerDict["test2"] = "answer2";
}
```

You can check whether the test exists in Dictionary with

```cs
guessAnswerDict.Contains("test1");
```

And get the answer value with

```cs
var answer = guessAnswerDict["test1"];
```

It will throw an exception when there are no key in dictionary, so you have to check it with `Contains`.

Of course you can merge these two with `TryGetValue`, like

```cs
string answer;
guessAnswerDict.TryGetValue("test1", out answer);

// Totally identical!!
guessAnswerDict.TryGetValue("test1", out var answer);
```

`TryGetValue` will return `false` if there are no key in the dictionary.

BTW, although C#'s default access modifier is `private`, it's always good to explicitly write it's `private`, which will increase the readability of your code :)

Comment: thankyou for your reply, how i change "test1" to variable so i can check to "test2" ,"test3",... when input text same as guess ?

Comment: Just what you said! `var test = userInput; var answer guessAnswerDict[userInput];`